# Django QuerySet Annotations - More efficient way?

Tags: django, annotations, django-class-based-views

In a class Based ListView I want to annotate each Post with the number of comments (this method works)

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)


    context['approved_comments'] = Comment.objects.values('post_id').annotate(c_count=Count('post_id')).filter(approved=True)
    return context
```

in my Template I do the following (which feels really inefficient)

```
{% for comment in approved_comments %}
    {% if post.id == comment.post_id %}
        {{comment.c_count}}
            
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gets me the result I want but I'm struggling to find a better way to deliver this since this seems really redundant.

I was trying to find a SO question that already deals with this but haven't found one so if you could point me to the link that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quadratic JOIN, you should not do that. You can simply annotate the `Post`s with the number of approved comments in the view:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
        napproved_comments=Count('comment', filter=Q(comment__approved=True))
    )
```

and then render this in the template with:

```
{{ post.napproved_comments }}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for :)